# Django Admin multiple template inheritance

Tags: python, django, templates, inheritance, admin

I thought it was a quite simple task but turns out it's not.
So, I have two different mixins to use on a Django admin class. they both have some codes in it with templates.

admin.py

```
class AdminMixin01(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "change_form1.html"

class AdminMixin02(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "change_form2.html"


class ModalAdmin(AdminMixin01, AdminMixin02, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

change_form1.html

```
{% extends "change_form.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    Form 1
{% endblock content %}
```

change_form2.html

```
{% extends "change_form.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    Form 2
{% endblock content %}
```

it's looks quite simple both python and html sides.
The problem is Django renders only first mixin's template and ignores the second mixin's template. In this case only `change_form1.html` rendered into original `change_form.html` template and no traces from `change_form2.html`.

The python codes in the both mixin are working except html codes. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Django's admin mixins, but just from knowing basic Python, it's obvious that your `ModalAdmin` will only have a single `change_form_template` property, depending on which of `AdminMixin01` and `AdminMixin02` comes first in the MRO. Which I guess is `AdminMixin01` because it comes first - which seems to be confirmed by what you're seeing. So I don't think you can do this the way you're trying to do it. (And I'm not sure what you're trying to do either. If it's just to get 2 different sub-templates shown in one, just use template inheritance or includes.)

Comment: yes, as you said django will not use both templates so i wrote the html codes into the original `change_form.html` then add checking variables both mixins. and wrap the html codes with `if` statements in the original html. im not happy with it but it worked. thanks a lot!

Comment: I solved it by copying some of the code to my new template, that had goodies form both. just like you said you did. pain in the B**